# How to send parametres to function and ethers at the same time using Ethers.js?

Tags: ethers.js

I  have a function with takes amount of token. And at the same time I want to send ethers. So how to write code using Ethers.js which will send ethers and give to transaction _amount value?

```
  function buy(uint256 _amount)
        public
        payable
    {
        token.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do so as follows:

```js
await contract.buy(inputAmount, { value: ethersValue });
```

Where both `inputAmount` and `ethersValue` are of type BigNumber.

You still need to add checks on the contract side to assert that user sent the correct `msg.value` (correct amount of Ethers) to the contract that are needed to buy the provided `inputAmount`.